# Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: redis

I'm trying to make edits to certain pages on our website on localhost:3000 but am experiencing the following error on specific pages.

```
Redis::CannotConnectError in FeaturesController#inventory
Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

ENV dump:

```
GATEWAY_INTERFACE: "CGI/1.2"
HTTP_ACCEPT:      "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: "gzip, deflate, sdch"
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: "en-US,en;q=0.8"
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL: "max-age=0"
REMOTE_ADDR: "127.0.0.1"
SERVER_NAME: "localhost"
SERVER_PROTOCOL: "HTTP/1.1"
```

In development.log file, it says:

```
Started GET "/en/ipad-pos-for-retail/inventory-management" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-05 17:02:22 -0400
Processing by FeaturesController#inventory as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"en"}
Geokit is using the domain: localhost
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 709ms

Redis::CannotConnectError (Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379     (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)):
app/controllers/features_controller.rb:46:in `inventory'


   Rendered /Users/benedictwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (10.4ms)
   Rendered /Users/benedictwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2.4ms)
   Rendered /Users/benedictwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (45.1ms)
```

Would really appreciate some help! Complete newbie here!

Comment: Do you have redis up?

Comment: Ah stupid me. Just installed it. That seems to have fixed the problem! Thank you so much! @Dbz